# How to fire onChange event and get the result JestJS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have an input in one of my classes which onChange updates some of the properties, according to what the user typed. So I want to call that input, give it a value, then it should go through the onChange method and then get the result from one of the properties. Here is my test case

```
it("test-input-value-1", async () => {
      const { getByTestId } = render(
        <>
      <Home />
      <Try typeracertext="dsa dsa"/>
      </>
      );
      const input = getByTestId("add-word-input");
      const inputWord = "For";
      userEvent.type(input, 'For')
      const userText = await getByTestId("userText");
      const typeracertext = getByTestId("typeracertext");
      await expect(userText.innerHTML).toBe(inputWord);
    });
```

and here is what I got
[image]
I don't have an idea why the result is empty when it has to be changed into the same word "For" that the input has.

EDIT: Here is the JSX Code as requested
Home.js:

```
const Game = () => {
        if (cantType === false) {
            return (
                <Try
                    typeracertext={typeracertext}
                    setWholeText={setWholeText}
                    setStartTyping={setStartTyping}
                    setEndTyping={setEndTyping}
                    setCountWords={setCountWords}
                    newGame={newGame} 
                    />
            )
        }

        else {
            return (
                <input readOnly />
            )
        }
    }
return (
 <span data-testid="userText" className="userTextHome">{wholeText}</span><div data-testid="typeracertext">
            </div>
            <div  data-testid="add-word-input2" className="box d">
                {Game()}

            </div>
    ...
```

Try.js:

```
//here is also the onChange method but it is not needed in this case as it is very long and I have explained what it does in the end (make a property to be equal to the input data)
    return (
        <div data-testid="add-word-input"><input name="add-word-input" placeholder="Message..." onChange={onChange}></input> </div>
    );
```

Comment: chekcout this https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/359

Comment: `expect` is not asynchronous, so the `await` keyword will not do anything.  You're looking for something like `waitFor` https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing user event on the div element, instead of input element.
Try moving attribute **data-testid** to **input** element in **Try.js** file:

```
return (
    <div><input data-testid="add-word-input" name="add-word-input" placeholder="Message..." onChange={onChange}></input> </div>
);
```

Working example: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-input-forked-g0ten6?file=/Input.js)

Input.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const Input = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          data-testid="add-word-input"
          name="add-word-input"
          placeholder="Message..."
          onChange={handleChange}
        ></input>
      </div>
      <label data-testId="test-label">{text}</label>
    </>
  );
};
```

Input.test.js:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { Input } from "./Input";

describe("Input", () => {
  it("should change", async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Input />);

    let input = getByTestId("add-word-input");
    expect(input).not.toBe(null);
    await userEvent.type(input, "for");

    let label = getByTestId("test-label");

    expect(label.textContent).toBe("for");
  });
});
```